# Service 'nginx' failed to build - Docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, npm

I have a `Dockerfile` that builds my frontend project. The content of it looks like that:

```
## Build
FROM node:16.14-slim as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

## Run
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/frontend-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

However, when try to run this, I'm getting following error in the console:

```
 => [build 3/7] COPY yarn.lock ./                                                                                  0.0s
 => [build 4/7] RUN yarn                                                                                           0.7s
 => [build 5/7] RUN yarn install                                                                                   0.7s
 => [build 6/7] COPY . .                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN npm run build                                                                            1.0s
------
 > [build 7/7] RUN npm run build:
#14 0.961
#14 0.961 > frontend-app@1.0.0 build
#14 0.961 > ng build --configuration production
#14 0.961
#14 0.966 sh: 1: ng: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 127
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build : Build failed
```

Do you have any recommendations to make it work?

Comment: `COPY yarn.lock ./` can be `COPY yarn.lock .` And the command `yarn` already installs the modules so you don't need to do `yarn install` later. Anyway, you need to install the cli in order to use `ng`: `RUN npm i -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Do you need to copy `package.json` along with the `yarn.lock` file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working file:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn-lock.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 80
```

You need the `package.json` (@David Maze said in the comments) and call npm (yarn or npm) only once, not `yarn ... yarn install`. I have added chmod -R 755 to the html folder. Without it nginx cannot get the files in assets folder or your favicon in most cases.

Optional is here my nxing.conf

```
events{}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```